# Regex for leading zeros and exclude normal zeros

Tags: regex

I am looking two traverse a list of alphanumerics that look like this:

0012-0103

I want to remove all leading zeros but keep the ones that belong to a given number value.

I have this which gets all the zeros:

```
/0*([1-9][0-9])?0/
```

Any suggestions. I am still review regex documentation.

Comment: which language are you using? and do you have decimals or just integers?

Comment: alphanumeric, or two numbers separated by a dash

Comment: I am using ruby and it is alphanumerics on either side of the dash but I want to account to for whole numbers like 20, 103, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
\b0+
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/kA9uJ9/3)

Explanation:

- `\b` word boundary.. this will check for all the boundaries which are separated by word and non word (digits are part of word)
- `0+` match more than one zeros

Therefore, this will match all those zeros which are not in middle..

Comment: is `\b` part of the standard regex, or does it require extended regex?

Comment: @Sobrique Generally, anchors are considered as extended regexes.. `\b` is also an anchor for word boundaries.

Comment: Thanks Sobrique. So this filters on both sides of the dash or do I even need to evaluate for that?

Comment: @porterhaus It works on both the sides.. check the demo :)

Comment: Sobrique thanks and thanks for the link to the demo that is a great tool.

Comment: Happy to help.. and I am not Sobrique :P

Comment: @PeeHaa added explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to give a precise answer without knowing the language and what exactly you want to do. I looked at your profile and it seems like you are probably doing this in ruby. Therefore, try this:

```
irb(main):001:0> string = "0012-0103"
=> "0012-0103"
irb(main):002:0> string.match(/0*([\d-]+)/).captures
=> ["12-0103"]
```